# Is it proper to use "too"/"as well" in a negated sentence?

Tags: grammar

The word **either** is what's usually used in such a case, but can we use **too** or **as well** too?
Example for the difference:

• It's better not to translate the first word, but it's bad not to translate the second *too*/*as well*.

• It's better not to translate the first word, but it's bad not to translate the second *either*.

Comment: 'It's better not to translate the first word, but it's bad not to translate the second either.' is incorrect. The first examples are clumsy. You've got a complicated 'It's better not to do A, and it's also bad **not** to do B.'

Comment: But *it's better not to translate **either** the first word **or** the second* is fine.